# Why will my background image not repeat?

Tags: html, css

What would cause the background image to not repeat even though I have repeat-x set for it? I need these TV's to go span the width of my x axis and I just cant figure it out.

```
#footer{
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#tvs{
   background-image: url(tvs-627x100.png);
    height: 100px;
    width: 627px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;}

<div id="footer">
Stop watching TV and write some code!
            </div>

<div id="tvs">
            </div>
```

Where am I going wrong here? Here is my jsfiddle too...

https://jsfiddle.net/dubh09mh/#&togetherjs=pxUyFRivNn

Comment: Thank you, but I think I'm missing something somewhere else... that didn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#tvs{
   background: transparent url(https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg) repeat-x left center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `repeat` this way:

```css
#tvs {
  background: url(https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg) repeat-x left center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 627px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

You need to specify an initial position too.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dubh09mh/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code
`background-size: contain;`

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9sy9w2x/).

Comment: That didn't work either. Cant I use !important to override whatever is causing it to not repeat?

Comment: You should avoid using !important if at all possible. When you say it doesn't work, does the fiddle not work for you or are you referring to your code locally? If it's the latter, please give me a few more details and I'll see what I can do to help you.

Comment: My code itself... It's like the image is fixed where it is and I'm not sure how that happened... Hold on and I'll update you with all of my code. Would you like to go to private chat?

Comment: I could chat later today, in the middle of a work project at the moment. I'll look at your code and get back to you, though. Actually, go ahead and get on the fiddle you just posted, I have a few minutes to chat.